# Is it possible to connect Sql Server Express database from Sequelize or TypeOrm?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, typeorm

I tried to connect to Sql Server Express 2019 database from Sequelize and TypeOrm, but unable to connect. I always get a timeout error.

I am using node.js

In Sequelize:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize("<dbname>", '<username>', '<password>', {
    host: "<remoteserver>\\SQLEXPRESS",
    port: 1433,
    dialect: "mssql",
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      idle: 10000
    }        
  });
```

Am I missing something?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no settings required to connect from typeorm or sequelize. I did not enable the Sql server browser.